# Zend Framework, SSL Routes, Fancybox, and XSS Issues

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, iframe, ssl, xss

**Set up:**

- I'm using Zend Framework
- I have a controller plugin that checks routes against my application settings and redirects to https if required or standard http if not.  I based my controller plugin on [this blog entry](http://www.kfx2.com/blog/2009/08/securing-a-url-with-zend-framework/).
- My forms "pop-up" using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

**Issues:**

If I'm on a non-ssl page when I initiate login, the form comes up correctly and performs the login process, but the JavaScript that calls the parent to close the Fancybox instance cannot do so because the domains are now different - https vs http

The login form and some others as well could be called from pages in either context, so I'm not sure how to go about resolving this.

The JavaScript that closes the Fancybox instance:

```
if (window.self !== window.top) {
    // is nested
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, here's how:

1. Added new SSL Route rule that's `allow_ssl` and added support for it in my controller plugin.  Routes that `allow_ssl` are not switched between HTTP and HTTPS.  This fixes pop-ups that can be called from a secure page, where it doesn't matter if they're secure or not.
2. Added a check in my login process that checks the originating request for login and sets an `is_ssl` flag in a 'Request' session namespace.  Once the login is successful I check the flag and redirect to the `close-popup` action via HTTP or HTTPS.  The `close-popup` actions is one that has the `allow_ssl` flag.